# How to click on a specific onclick valueusing Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What can I do to replace `find_element_css_selector` in `Selenium Python` to click on a specific `onclick` value

```
(javascript:unitsSelectUnit(1))
```

The browser is google chrome

```
browser.get("http://eatsmart.housing.illinois.edu/NetNutrition/46#")
browser.find_element_css_selector("a[onclick*=javascript:unitsSelectUnit(1);]").click()
html = browser.page_source
time.sleep(2)
print(html)

# close web browser
browser.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

To click on the element with text as ***Ikenberry Dining Center (IKE)*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  driver.get("http://eatsmart.housing.illinois.edu/NetNutrition/46#")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "New"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("http://eatsmart.housing.illinois.edu/NetNutrition/46#")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick*='unitsSelectUnit(1)']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("http://eatsmart.housing.illinois.edu/NetNutrition/46#")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@onclick, 'unitsSelectUnit(1)')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: eatsmart]

Comment: It keeps opening and closing within 1 second, do I change the 20 or the sleep time to help keep the browser open for a while.

Comment: _`20`_ in `WebDriverWait(driver, 20)` is more then enough. Do you have the latest Chrome/ChromeDriver?

Comment: I mean what if I want to keep it permanently open

Comment: Also thank you for the help, the code worked out and I used that method for the rest of the scraper.

Answer (score 1):

This `CSS_SELECTOR`

```
a[onclick*=javascript:unitsSelectUnit(1);]
```

that you are using in your code is wrong. Basically, you are missing `''`

`CSS_SELECTOR` follow the below **syntax**:

```
node_name[attribute_name = 'attribute_value']
```

You can cross verify as well by following the below steps:

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `css selector` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

This `a[onclick*=javascript:unitsSelectUnit(1);]` won't match anything, where as `a[onclick*='javascript:unitsSelectUnit(1);']` will match `Ikenberry Dining Center (IKE)` node.

Now If you want to click on it, please use the below code:

**Code:**

```
browser.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
browser.get("http://eatsmart.housing.illinois.edu/NetNutrition/46#")


try:
    btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick*='javascript:unitsSelectUnit(1);']")))
    btn.click()
except:
    print("Could not click on button")
    pass
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```